# Not able to remove tab border from tabs in angular 4 using bootsrap

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap with angular 4 , the tabs are visible I want to remove the bottom border.
[This border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My15a.png)

```css
tab>active {
  color: rgb(58, 45, 128)
}

tabset {
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Home"></tab>
    <tab heading="Profile"></tab>
    <tab heading="About us"></tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: box-shadow maybe .. try `box-shadow:none`

Comment: can you create a plunk ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get rid of the border altogether as follows ? It's not like the tabs are being highlighted with their own borders.

```
tabset{
margin: 0;
outline: 0;
border:none !important;
}
```

Edit:
Since the order of stylesheets being applied matters, so you can keep following code in your style.css. You can use id for your subset of div element that contains those tabs and then apply your border-bottom:none; to the css code that only points to the tabset of that div that has matching id. For e.g.

```
#myDiv > tabset
{
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom:none !important;
}
```

Comment: .nav-tabs{borde-bottom:none} ? or .nav.nav-tabs{border-bottom:none}?

Comment: @Punit try the new sample code. Notice that I added !important; Let us know if it works.

Comment: No it did'nt wort still, it only works when I add to style.css and not the component's css

Comment: @Punit you said "when I add to style.css... " 
When you add what to style.css ?

Comment: When I add border-bottom :none in style.css then only it works

Comment: @Punit then you can keep following code in your style.css. you can use id for your subset of div element that contains those tabs and then apply your border-bottom:none; to the css code that only points to the tabset of that div that has matching id. For e.g. 

#myDiv > tabset
{
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom:none !important;
}